# Cassandra wide row with every column as composite key

Tags: cassandra, key, row, composite

I have a wide row table with column

`page_id int, user_id int, session_tid timeuuid and end_time timestamp`

with partition key = `user_id`

I need to do multiple queries on the table, some based on one column and some based on another - and it turns out that I have cases with `where` clause on every column

As Cassandra doesnt allow me to use `where` clause on non-indexed, non-key column, is it ok if I make all of the columns my composite key? (currently all but `end_time` column are already composite key, with `user_id` as the partition key)

Answer (score 3):

Making all columns as part of the primary key will not allow you to perform `where` conditions to each column in the way you're thinking.

To make an easy example if you create such a primary key

```
PK(key1, key2, key3, key4)
```

you **won't** be able to perform a query like

```
select * from mytable where key2 = 'xyz';
```

Because the rule is that you have to *follow the order of keys* to create a "multiple-where" condition.

So valid queries with multiple `where` are the following:

```
select * from mytable where key1 = 'xyz' and key2 = 'abc';
select * from mytable where key1 = 'xyz' and key2 = 'abc' and key3 = 11;
select * from mytable where key2 = 'xyz' and key2 = 'abc' and key3 = 11 and key4 = 2014;
```

You can ask for `keyN` only providing `keyN-1`

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks for your answer - yes I just figured that out. However from the performance perspective if I have a wide row table with n columns, 1 of them as paritition key and n-2 rows as composite keys ans 1 normal value col would there be any performance impact that I should be aware of? (Im aware about the fact that a wide row need to reside in the same partition but i don't expect the col to grow to more than several hundred thousands)